# How to modifyPaymentRequest() in Commerce 2?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce2, hook

Looks that I really used every functionality in my plugin that changed or has been removed in Commerce 2. :(

I need to modify paypal `transactionId` and `description` what i did as follows in Commerce 1:

```
public function commerce_modifyPaymentRequest(array $request){
  // set (paypal) payment description
  $request['transactionId'] = substr($request['order']['number'], 0, 7) . "*";
  $request['description'] = "Bestell ID: " . substr($request['order']['number'], 0, 7) . "*";
}
```

How can I do that in Commerce 2?